# std::map and std::set does not return bool with a hint

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap, stdset

How can I implement this function which apparently does not exist (why?) efficiently:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> std::set::insert (const_iterator hint, const value_type& val);
```

I want to insert a value efficiently (with a hint), and at the same time have a bool which tells me if it has been inserted (this is essential).

Why does such function not exist. I could not come up with a possibility to do that efficiently?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: define efficiently... why do you need to be sure? is this a multi thread problem where the set is a shared resource and this could be fixed with a lock? In general inserting elements in a set will happen if the set is already allocated, unless you are copying huge elements and breaking memory havoc in the process.

Comment: @Claudiordgz Presumably, he means getting the same amortized constant time insertion performance that the other `set|map::insert` overload that takes an insertion hint yields. And what does multithreading have to do with this? As for your last sentence, I have no idea what you're going on about!

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. But when you are inserting into a `set` it returns the iterator to the position you inserted. @Gabriel This seems like a good proposition to add to the `std::set`. In the meantime you could binary search for the element you are inserting in the set, if it exists then don't insert. If it does, check the iterator for a valid position. Remember that inserting an invalid position is passed you could get into problems.

Comment: I mean exactly what Praetorian pointed out :-)!

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is assumed that if you have a hint iterator you acquired it via `find`, `equal_range`, `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`, or are inserting a sorted sequence, so if you need to know you can check whether `*hint` (or possibly `*prev(hint)`) is equivalent to `val` yourself:

```
iterator hint = s.lower_bound(val);
// (hint == s.end() || !(*hint < val)) && (hint == s.begin() || *prev(hint) < val)
if (hint != s.end() && !(val < *hint))
    ; // equivalent
else
    s.insert(hint, val); // guaranteed to insert
```

Note that insert-with-hint is *not* guaranteed to perform in O(1) if it fails to insert (i.e. `*hint` is equivalent to `val`), so you should check that the insert will succeed before calling `insert` anyway.

Similarly, for a hint iterator derived from `upper_bound`:

```
iterator hint = s.upper_bound(val);
// (hint == s.end() || val < *hint) && (hint == s.begin() || !(val < *prev(hint)))
if (hint != s.begin() && !(*prev(hint) < val))
    ; // val is equivalent to *prev(hint)
else
    s.insert(hint, val); // guaranteed to insert
```

Comment: ``assert(!(*hint < val))`` <<<--- This assert is always true, for what is this needed?

Comment: @Gabriel it's just documenting the behavior of `lower_bound`; I'll turn it into a comment.

Comment: ahh ok, now i understand :-), but this is a solution if one takes the hint from such a function, if one has some other hint derived by one-self there is no way around a new stl overload for the ``std::set`` i think...?

Comment: @Gabriel it depends on how you derived the hint iterator; if you are expecting the hint to be used then it must be either the `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` position.

Comment: In C++11 it tries to insert before the hint always.

Comment: @ecatmur Prior to 11, apparently after!

Comment: @Yakk yes, but if your insertion fails then it makes a difference whether `val` is equivalent to `*hint` or `*prev(hint)`, or some other position entirely.

Comment: @ecatmur my point is that in 11, the hint only helps if `*hint >= x` and `*prev(hint)<=x` (ignoring fencepost cases).  Test that and you also know if `x` was already there.  Then fall back on non-`hint` insert.  In 03, tests are annoyingly different.

Comment: @Yakk by my reading of 23.2.4p2 if the insertion fails then performance is logarithmic, so you need `*prev(hint) < x < *hint`. But if you know where the hint came from you may be able to guarantee at least one side already obtains.